# Table as a list item - location of bullet

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make the bullet to be shown near the top of the table instead of somewhere in the middle.

To achieve this task, it seems I need to change the `vertical-align` of `td`. But why `td {vertical-align: top}` doesn't help?

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>a</p>
          <p>b</p>
          <p>c</p>
          <p>d</p>
          <p>e</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>a</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>a</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>a</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>a</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it an `inline-table` then use `vertical-align`

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  display:inline-table;
  vertical-align:top;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>a</p>
          <p>b</p>
          <p>c</p>
          <p>d</p>
          <p>e</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>a</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>a</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>a</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>a</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. Are there any disadvantages of making the table inline?

Comment: @johnc.j. not really, since you are making it with:100% it will behave the same way as table